# Redis: append to position of string

Tags: redis, append

Let's say I have a key "test" with value "Hello world!".
Is there anything that allows me to insert a comma next to hello? Something like

```
INSERT key value pos
```

or do I have to replace it manually and save the whole text again using SET?

Thanks!

Comment: you will have to do what you said: replace the whole value

Comment: @akonsu this is simply false

Answer (score 0):

Use `setrange`

```
SETRANGE key 11 ","
```

[Source](http://redis.io/commands/setrange)

Comment: SETRANGE actually overwrites the data, so it's not what I need